# Drools complex event processing

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing

I want to write a complex rule where i need to trigger a rule when any network ip hits to an application over a 10 minutes window. i have challenges where ip's will be varying and i am not sure how to keep the track of each ip that has hit the application.

```
rule "IP hit exceeds 10 times"
no-loop
when

    "some ip hitting more than 10 times"  over window:time(10m);

         $cnt: count(1); $cnt >= 10)
     then
        System.out.println("IP hit exceeds 10 times");

end
```

I need logic for this part of code **"some ip hitting"**.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [Drools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/), you can see that the `accumulate` function used in conjunction with a `window` will do exactly what you need.

Basically, `accumulate` collects items across a collection -- if we weren't using sliding windows you could use this to get sub-lists or figure out sums across list of events. There's also a similar function called `collect`, but I'll use `accumulate` in this example.

Anyway, let's say that you have a class defined something like this:

```
class IpHitEvent {
  private String ip;
  // getters and setters
}
```

Then you could leverage `accumulate` along with the built-in `count` method to get the number of IP hits for a specified IP.

```
rule "Single IP Hits > 10"
when
  $ip: String() // Target IP -- set based on your own logic
  Integer( this > 10 ) from accumulate(IpHitEvent( ip == $ip ) over window:time(10m), count(1))
then
  System.out.println($ip + " has hit more than 10 times!");
  // logic for when IP hit count exceeds 10
end
```